# Display a (xlsx file)worksheet on gui using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to display a (xlsx file)worksheet on gui using Tkinter?
It can be in any format.

```
def display():
    filepath="D:\old\fresh.xlsx"
    os.system(filepath)
w = Label(top, text=time.strftime("%c"))
k=Tkinter.Button(top,text="See all result on Ms excel",command= helloCallBack)
B=Tkinter.Button(top,text="Enter to get new data",command= helloCallBack)
load=Image.open("498064609.jpg")
background_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
background_label = Label(top, image=background_image)
k.pack()
B.grid(row=2,column=6)
B.pack()
w.pack()
```

This leads to (not responding)when I press the button('See all result on Ms excel')

Comment: Do you want to display *the* excel file, or just the data within it?

Comment: Yes, there's a way. What part of the problem are you struggling with? Have you researched how to read and parse xlsx files? Do you know how to create tkinter GUIs? Do you know how to display data in a tabular format?

Comment: I want to display the excel file

Comment: Ok, so you're asking "will you write this code for me"?

Comment: of course not, see my  edited post actually i am week in english sorry for my words,

Comment: And i replied to the first comment

Answer (score -1):

Using [Tktable](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/TkTable) and python3

```
import tkinter as tk
import tktable

root = tk.Tk()
table = tktable.Table(root, rows=10, cols=4)
table.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This doesn't display an xlsx file, it just creates an empty table.

Comment: @BryanOakley I wrote that answer before OP made his edits

Comment: I don't see why that changes anything. The original question asked about displaying xlsx data, this answer doesn't address that.